# Stream large responses with jersey, asynchronously

Tags: java, servlets, asynchronous, jersey, jax-rs

I want to allow clients (including very slow clients) to download large files from an JAX-RS (jersey) web service and I'm stuck. It seems like async fatures in JAX-RS do not support this.

- `AsyncResponse` solves the issue if you have to wait for a resource to become available on server side, but then you are only allowed to call  `AsyncResponse.resume(Object)` only once. After that, the response is handled normally. Slow or malicious clients will blocks a worker thread until all bytes are transferred. No async IO here.
- `ChunkedOutput` in jersey stores the chunks in an unbounded in-memory queue and does not offer any public interface to check the size of that queue. It's designed for a slow stream of small chunks. Enough slow clients will eventually cause an `OutOfMemoryError`.
- `StreamingOutput` is not asynchronous at all. The `StreamingOutput.write(OutputStream)` method is supposed to block until all bytes are written.
- The Servlet 3.x API does support what I need, but I cannot find a way to get to servlet level (`HttpServletRequest.startAsync`) from within an JAX-RS request handler without breaking jerseys internals. -> `IllegalStateException`

Am I not seeing the obvious solution?

Answer (score 6):

With reasonably new versions of jersey and jetty, the following works:

- Inject `@Suspended AsyncResponse` into your jax-rs request handler method. This tells jersey to enter async-mode and keep the request open.
- Inject `@Context HttpServletRequest` to access servlet-level APIs.
- Call `HttpServletRequest.getAsyncContext()` instead of `HttpServletRequest.startAsync()`, because jersey already switched to async mode and doing so again results in an `IllegalStateException` (that was my problem from above).
- Use this `AsyncContext` as you'd do in a servlet environment. Jersey does not complain.
- Once you are done, call `AsyncContext.complete()` and then `AsyncResponse.cancel()`. The latter is optional I think.

I managed to serve a 10GB file to 100 concurrent clients this way. The thread count never exceeded ~40 threads and memory consumption was low. The throughput was about ~3GB/s on my laptop, which is kinda impressive.

```
@GET
public void doAsync(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
                    @Context HttpServletRequest servletRequest)
        throws IOException {
    assert servletRequest.isAsyncStarted();
    final AsyncContext asyncContext = servletRequest.getAsyncContext();
    final ServletOutputStream s = asyncContext.getResponse().getOutputStream();

    s.setWriteListener(new WriteListener() {

        volatile boolean done = false;

        public void onWritePossible() throws IOException {
            while (s.isReady()) {
                if(done) {
                    asyncContext.complete();
                    asyncResponse.isCancelled();
                    break;
                } else {
                    s.write(...);
                    done = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem like you. I needed to transfer big amounts of data between two instances of my application. Initially I used simple StreamingOutput approach but very soon I understood that this will not works as the client party was quite slower compared to server party and I have been getting TimeOutException. I was able to solve this by setting up my Grizzly server. In this way I can transfer with the StreamingOutput approach hundreds of megabytes.My code for setting the timeout is like this:

```
Collection<NetworkListener> listeners = server.getListeners(); 
for(NetworkListener listener : listeners) {
    final TCPNIOTransport transport = listener.getTransport();
    transport.setKeepAlive(true);
    transport.setWriteTimeout(0, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```